# Rails jquery fullcalendar can't display extra field in event

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

I'm using jquery fullcalendar in a rails app.
Currently it displays the event.title field in the month display.  I would like it to also display and additional field = workorder.wonum

I found this solution here on Stackoverflow.

```
eventRender: (event, element) ->
  element.find(".fc-event-title").html(event.title + ": <span>" + event.workorder.wonum + "</span>")
```

That code displays the event.title and then "undefined".  If I change event.workorder.wonum to event.description --> that works.

Could I do this by changing the event.title in the controller where the json is being created?

Something like this (it doesn't work):

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @events, :only => [:title => :title + :workworder.wonum] }
end
```

Thanks!!

Comment: In your code above, you have `event.workorder_num`, not `_id`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

The solution was to combine the workorder.wonum with the title:

```
 # need to override the json view to return what full_calendar is expecting.
 # http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/
 def as_json(options = {})
  {
    :id => self.id,
    :title => "#{self.workorder.wonum} #{self.title}",
    :description => self.description || "",
    :start => starts_at.rfc822,
    :end => ends_at.rfc822,
    :allDay => self.all_day,
    :recurring => false,
    :url => Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.event_path(id),
    :color => "blue",
    :backgroundColor => "blue",
    :borderColor => "black",
    :textColor  => "white"
 }

end
```